# Matrix factorization code in C#

Tags: c#

I have to factorize one matrix into two matrices and that's why I am looking for a matrix factorization code in C#. 
I really appreciate if you know one please introduce me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you show some code and explain where exactly you're having troubles or show an example of what you want to do?

Comment: There's **[this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj863137.aspx)** in msdn which i could find **with a simple google search.**

Answer (score 1):

[Math.Net.Numerics](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) has support for e.g.

QR decomposition 
http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double.Factorization/QR.htm

and LU decomposition
http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Generic.Factorization/LU%601.htm